# Polkadot Explorer: decode storage system.events

Tags: polkadot-js, custom-types, decode

I was doing some testing and sent a transaction on a custom substrate chain. On the polkadot explorer, the block which held the transaction had an error. The transaction completed; however, the explorer showed:

`Unable to retrieve the specified block details. Unable to decode storage system.events:: createType(Vec<EventRecord>):: Vec<EventRecord>:: Decoded input doesn't match input, received`

What is this error? And is there anything I could do to fix it?

Thank you!

Edit: https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/explorer

Comment: What explorer? Please add more details here 

Comment: Sorry! I was using this https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/explorer

Comment: no worries - but this isn't a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example so its very hard to help