# PolkadotJS system and storage events are not being decoded and shown properly

Tags: polkadot-js

I found a perhaps similar question here : [Polkadot Explorer: decode storage system.events](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/polkadot-explorer-decode-storage-system-events)
[image: Error]

We are running a custom parachain with frontier on a local testnet and while the transactions go through fine, we are seeing these. Any idea where to look?

Here's some more error messages from the web console:
[image: console err]

Comment: That looks an issue with the versions, are you running polkadotJS locally? And what version of Frontier?

Comment: Frontier is on `polkadot-v0.9.30` and I am running this is from the webapp.